# PHP Login access not restricted

Tags: php, login-system

Hope you can help me with this, (again in some cases!)

I have a php login system which is using a mysql database connection, first the user fills in a login form:

`Code: admin/index.php:`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style-new.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function formfocus() {
  document.getElementById('myusername').focus();
}
window.onload = formfocus;
</script>

<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form action="/?module=admin&n=checklogin" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Administrator Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input type="text" name="myusername" id="myusername" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword" tabindex="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td> <button type="submit" name="Submit" tabindex="3">Login</button>
 <img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" width="16" height="16" style="display: none"/>
 <script>
    $("button").click(function () {
    $("img").show("slow");
    });
  </script>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
<p align="center">Clicked on the wrong link? <a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Click Here</a></p>
</div>
```

This is then sent for verification by checklogin.php:

`Code: checklogin.php:`

```
<?php 
sleep(3)
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style-new.css" type="text/css" />

<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="david_bpd"; // Mysql username 
$password="documents123456"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="david_bpd"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row


$cdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cuser");
$cdata = mysql_num_rows($cdata);
echo $cdata;


if($count==1){
//If a user is not already logged on
if($cdata == 1){
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=/?module=admin&n=Login_unavailable'>";
}
else {
//Register username
echo $myusername;
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;

var_dump($_SESSION['myusername']);

$_SESSION['myusername'] == $myusername;


$sql2="INSERT INTO cuser(myusername)VALUES('$myusername')";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?module=admin&n=Login_success">';

}
}
elseif($count==0) {
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?module=admin&n=Login_Unsuccessful">';
}
?>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

It is then re-registered using `admin/Login_name.php:` which checks the last access name in the mysql database and registers it again

```
<?php
/* Mysql connection */
$tbl_name="cuser"; // Table name

$query = "SELECT MAX(`id`) AS 'max' FROM $tbl_name";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$max = $row['max'];
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id= '$max'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$row1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1);

//check username
$myusername=$row1[1];

//register username
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;

?>
```

The problem i have is I have to restrict access to the the admin area by using this:

`Code:`

```
<?php
session_start ();
    if ($_REQUEST ['module'] == 'admin' && $_REQUEST ['n'] != 'index' && $_REQUEST ['n'] != 'Login_Unsuccessful' && $_REQUEST ['n'] != 'checklogin' && $_REQUEST ['n'] != 'Logout' && $_REQUEST ['n'] != 'Login_name') {

        include ("admin/Login_name.php");
        // var_dump ( $myusername );
        //echo $myusername;
        //echo "<br />";
        //echo "<br />";
        if (isset ( $_SESSION ['myusername'] )) {
            //var_dump($myusername);
            //echo "SESSION IS SET";
            if ($_SESSION ['myusername'] == $myusername) {
                //echo "User should be allowed to be on page";
            } else {
                //echo"User not allowed";
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?module=admin&n=index">';
            }

        } else {
            //var_dump(($_SESSION['myusername']));
            //echo "SESSION IS NOT SET(username not registered)";

            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?module=admin&n=index">';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

The problem i have found is that if an administrator is already logged in a person that hasn't logged in can still access the restricted areas but i dont want that to happen.

I think it may have something to do with the if statements in the last bit of source code however i do not know.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

P.S. Sorry for the long post the only way to describe fully!

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but you should not start the session after outputing html code in your checklogin.php

Comment: Seriously consider using a framework like CodeIgniter

Comment: I was told that I need to start the session in order to be able to register the username at the bottom

Comment: why not use php's header() function for redirects?

Comment: because headers cause errors because they are set in a index.php file which applies to certain elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to check user login by doing something like this.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['admin']){
  // let user to admin page
}else{
  // deny access
}
```

so in your when you are processing the form just set the `$_SESSION['user']` and set `$_SESSION['user']['admin']` to true;

Again this is a simple login method.

Answer (score 1):

I have another idea for this.

Instead of doing double query to check user and active users, you can do it with a single join query between table users table active users

table user contains fields

- user_id
- user_name
- password
- etc...

table active_users contains fields,

- user_id
- login_time
- session_id
- etc...

then you can do select join query to check wheter the user has a valid info from table users and the user has checked in the table active_users.

Then for the restricted areas, you can check it against the user sessions. If users try to access any pages/areas, do the receck user privileges assigned based on user session.

Hope this could help.